# Heap break does not change after malloc

Tags: c, macos, memory, memory-management, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("main: %p\n", main);
    printf("brk before malloc: %p\n", sbrk(0));
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
    printf("malloc at %p\n", a);
    printf("brk after malloc: %p\n", sbrk(0));
}
```

Output:

```
main: 0x108f9ae90
brk before malloc: 0x8fbc000
malloc at 0x7fb380c02b40
brk after malloc: 0x8fbc000
```

Why break address does not change after malloc? In addition, why is the top of the heap (break) address so far away from malloc'ed address, and it's even lower than the address of main, which is in the text segment?

If I understand correctly, the return value of the second sbrk call should have the largest value among all because it's the address of the top of the heap, and heap data should have a higher address than text segment. I was expecting 2nd brk > malloc'ed addr > 1st brk > main, but apparently it's not the case here.

Comment: Are you sure that `malloc` is implemented using `sbrk`? Perhaps it's implemented using memory mapping (`mmap`)?

Comment: As I read `sbrk()` man page, it just reports the end of uninitialized data. That memory could have been allocated/set aside at startup an your small allocation does not require any change.

Comment: Note: the "uninitialized data" segment is not necessarilly the same as the heap.

Comment: I see you have accepted an answer that talks about the macOS specific implementation of `sbrk`. Yet you have tagged this question with `linux`. If the answer is correct then your tagging is wrong. If the tagging is correct then the answer is wrong. Please don't accept answers that are wrong, or use tags that are wrong (and therefore misleading).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Changed the tag. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current Mac OS X implementation of sbrk is an emulation, and has a maximum allocation of 4 megabytes. See [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.12/emulated/brk.c) .